# Why gaming with mouse feels so weird?

Tags: usb, mouse, trackpad, games

I recently bought a macbook pro retina 2012 and later tried some fps game, e.g. Team Fortress 2. I plugged an usb mouse and noticed my it's movement is kinda weird or like unresponsive or something. It seems like my mouse movement has some kind of inertia, smoothing, acceleration or something, but it doesn't feel comfortable when gaming. Sometimes even a touchpad seems easier to play with. What am I experiencing and how can I make it like in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X has a bit of mouse input lag and acceleration.

You can fix this by installing [**SmoothMouse**](http://smoothmouse.com). It works great for me in CS:GO. You can enable and disable it separately for the mouse and trackpad from the preference pane.

Comment: As for actual input lag in Source games on OS X, I'm in the process of writing a post regarding just that aspect and how to fix it. It's not complete yet but I'll add it to this answer when it is.